# How to extract multiple coded values from multiple columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem I want to solve. I have a Big Database (millions of rows per column) with multiple columns. In Column A, I have patients. In Column B, I have diagnosis types (ICD-10, or ICD-9). In Column C, I have many diagnosis codes (say J280, J285, J2854 for ICD-10; and 478, 485, 490 for ICD-9). In Column D, I have diagnosis dates.

What I want to do is, I want to extract into a new dataframe, all patients from column A who satisfy specific diagnosis codes in Column C and specific diagnosis types in Column B. In the next step, I want to divide the diagnosis dates to quarters (per annum) and mark with 1 the patients from the previous step who belong to diagnosis quarter 1, or diagnosis quarter 2, etc.

What I tried so far was to use np.select, but it is not very practical as I have to hard-code all different diagnosis codes and types per quarter:

```
conditions=[(diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd_type'] == 'ICD10') & (diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd'] == 'J1289'),
(diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd_type'] == 'ICD10') & (diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd'] == 'J129'),
(diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd_type'] == 'ICD9') & (diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd'] == '478'),
(diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd_type'] == 'ICD9') & (diagnosis_df['diagnosis_cd'] == '480')]

outputs=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

data['newcolumn']=np.select(conditions, output)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show us some example data. Great would be a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also where in your described process are you stuck?

Comment: Is your database a SQL DB or a Pandas dataframe, etc?

Comment: I try to do this with Pandas df.